# How to upload a file to a certain folder in Cloudinary? Node JS

Tags: node.js, file-upload, cloudinary

In cloudinary I have a folder called images, I want to upload the files into that folder.
I have done set up the cloudinary config. The storage options and the file filter has been done. In the request, I send the post request that will upload the file to cloudinary, but not to the folder. How can I upload a file to a certain folder in Cloudinary?

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, './images/');
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, '-') + file.originalname);
  }
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (!file.mimetype.match(/jpe|jpeg|png|gif$i/)) {
    cb(new Error('File is not supported'), false);
    return;
  }

  cb(null, true);
};

const upload = multer({
  storage,
  fileFilter
});

router.post('/',  upload.single('profileImage'), async (req,res) => {
  const result = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.file.path);
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're performing the upload request you can specify a set of options to be used for that upload. In these options, you can specify the 'public_id' (filename) and/or 'folder' of where the file should be stored.

For example, to upload a file to a folder called 'test', you can use the code below:

```
cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(
    "path/to/file",
    {
        folder: "test",
    },
    function(error, result) {
        console.log(error,result);
    }
);
```

You can find out all available options for the upload method via this section of the documentation:
https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload_method

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57307399/6243352) didn't work for me using `"cloudinary": "^1.25.1"`. The callback was never invoked. I assume it's not treating the second argument as a configuration object, but I didn't bother looking into it further since I would rather use promises anyway.

For v2, the [promise-based upload API](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_image_and_video_upload#node_js_image_upload) worked nicely:

```js
cloudinary.v2.uploader
  .upload(req.body.dataURL, {folder: "some-folder"})
  .then(result => {
    res.json({data: result});
    console.log(result);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    res.json({error: err.message});
    console.error(err);
  });
```

The docs don't show a `.catch`, but I added one anyway, since any request can fail.